# onmouseover with javascript

Tags: javascript, onmouseover, onmouseout

I would like `div a` and `div b` to switch places when the mouse is over `div b` then switch back when mouse leaves `div a`. But its super glitchy and will switch even when mouse hasn't left `div a`. How do i get it to **not** run `navMouseOut` when mouse is still in `div a`, and why is it doing this. (please test code to see whats wrong)

```js
document.getElementById("b").onmouseover = function() {
  navMouseOver()
};
document.getElementById("a").onmouseout = function() {
  navMouseOut()
};

function navMouseOver() {
  document.getElementById("a").style = ("top: 50%;");
  document.getElementById("b").style = ("top: 40%; ");
}

function navMouseOut() {
  document.getElementById("a").style = ("top: 40%;");
  document.getElementById("b").style = ("top: 50%;");
}
```

```css
#a {
  position: fixed;
  top: 40%;
  left: 20%;
  background-color: red;
}

#b {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 20%;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div id="a">
  <p>content a</p>
</div>
<div id="b">
  <p>content b...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: As an aside, you don't need anonymous functions to wrap the calls to your other functions, just say `document.getElementById("b").onmouseover = navMouseOver;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use onmouseenter instead of onmouseover

```
document.getElementById("b").onmouseenter = function() {
navMouseOver()
};

document.getElementById("a").onmouseout = function() {
navMouseOut()
};
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle that shows how to do that: https://jsfiddle.net/8ohoe1dm/

Comment: This answer would be more helpful if you added an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is on propagation, let see this function onmouseout,even if you leave your mouse out of P element but still in DIV,  onmouseout will still execute.

you can write html like this:

```
<div id="a">
  content a
</div>
<div id="b">
  content b...
</div>
```

or use stoppropagation() or cancelBubble()

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when the elements switch position, the `mouseover` and `mouseenter` events are fired as the element that is newly positioned on the mouse. To prevent this you can use a flag that is toggled true to false that decides whether or not to run the repositioning code.

```js
var target1 = document.getElementById("mouseoverTarget1");
var switching = false;
var inStartingPosition = true;

target1.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  if (!switching) {
    switching = true;
    target1.style.top = inStartingPosition ? "50px" : "0px";
    target2.style.top = inStartingPosition ? "-50px" : "0px";
    inStartingPosition = inStartingPosition ? false : true;
    console.log("mouseover target 1");
    setTimeout(() => {
      switching = false;
    }, 100);
  }
});

var target2 = document.getElementById("mouseoverTarget2");

target2.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
  if (!switching) {
    switching = true;
    target1.style.top = inStartingPosition ? "50px" : "0px";
    target2.style.top = inStartingPosition ? "-50px" : "0px";
    inStartingPosition = inStartingPosition ? false : true;
    console.log("mouseover target 2");
    setTimeout(() => {
      switching = false;
    }, 100);
  }
});
```

```css
#mouseoverTarget1, #mouseoverTarget2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: relative;
}

#mouseoverTarget1 {
  background-color: red;
}

#mouseoverTarget2 {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="mouseoverTarget1"></div>
<div id="mouseoverTarget2"></div>
```

Comment: *"mouseover event repeatedly fires while the mouse is over an element."* - That's true only in that it bubbles, so it fires again if the mouse is moved over the element's children. Simply remaining over an element doesn't cause it to fire repeatedly. But yes, mouseenter doesn't bubble.